# Carrinho de compras vazio retorna Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

Sempre que o carrinho de compras está vazio, eu abro e mostra os erros. Mas se compro um produto ele desaparece.

Como resolvo isso ?

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...carrinho.php on
>   line 152

```
foreach($_SESSION['monalisa_produto'] as $id => $qtd){
    $total_frete_produtos += $_SESSION['valor_frete_'.$id]*$qtd;
}
```

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...carrinho.php on
>   line 93

```
foreach($_SESSION['monalisa_produto'] as $id => $qtd){  
    $_SESSION['valor_frete_'.$id] = str_replace(",",".",$_SESSION['valor_frete_'.$id]);
    $_SESSION['valor_frete'] += $_SESSION['valor_frete_'.$id];  
}
```

Eu vi um post que dizia para colocar um `if` antes do `foreach`, seria correto ?

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece porque `$_SESSION['monalisa_produto']` não está definido ainda, ou tem um valor não iterável. Você pode usar:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['monalisa_produto']) && is_array($_SESSION['monalisa_produto']))) {
    // foreach
}
```

Comment: Obs: esse código não vai funcionar se vc estiver usando algo diferente de array para armazenar os itens do carrinho, mas não acredito que seja o seu caso.